# How to implement a Linear Feedback Shift Register in Verilog using for loops?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog

I tried implementing LFSR using Verilog , but I am unable to get the output properly, please check the verilog code for both module and test bench below:-

```
    //LFSR.v
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps
module AUTO_LFSR #(parameter Length=8, initial_state=8'b1000_0001, parameter[1:Length]tp_coeff=8'b1111_0011)
( 
input clk,rst,
output reg [1:Length]Y
);
integer cell_ptr;

always @(posedge clk)

if(rst==1'b1)
Y<=initial_state;
else
    begin

        for(cell_ptr=2;cell_ptr<=Length;cell_ptr=cell_ptr+1)
            begin
                if(tp_coeff[cell_ptr+1]==1)
                    Y[cell_ptr]=Y[cell_ptr-1]^Y[Length];
                else

                    Y[cell_ptr]<=Y[cell_ptr-1];
                    Y[1]<=Y[Length];

            end
    end

endmodule


//LFSR_tb.v
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
`include"LFSR.v"
module LFSR_tb();
parameter Length=8;
parameter initial_state=8'b1000_0001;
parameter[1:Length]tp_coeff=8'b1111_0011;
reg clk,rst;
wire [1:Length]Y;
AUTO_LFSR dut(.clk(clk),.rst(rst),.Y(Y));

initial
begin
    clk=0;
    rst=1;
end

always
#1 clk=~clk;
initial
begin

rst=0;
#100 $monitor("This is the cllk %b %b %b",tp_coeff,Y,clk);
#200 $finish;

end
endmodule
```

This is my output:
[image: output]

I implemented it exactly how it was mentioned in Ciletti book:[image: M . D. Ciletti Advanced Digital Design]

Comment: Note that you never actually asserted your reset signal.

Comment: Even if I assert rst=1 in my testbench , the output is same .

Comment: Your code doesn't show that change. If I make the obvious change and simulate it using iverilog, it works just fine.

Comment: Sir, can you send your code , I have already tried it several times but still the output has X in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code simulates just fine in `iverilog`:

```
/* lfsr.v */

`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module AUTO_LFSR #(
  parameter Length=8,
            initial_state = 8'b1000_0001,
  parameter[1:Length]tp_coeff=8'b1111_0011
) ( 
  input clk, rst,
  output reg [1:Length] Y
);

  integer cell_ptr;

  always @(posedge clk)
    if (rst==1'b1)
      Y <= initial_state;
    else begin
      for (cell_ptr = 2; cell_ptr <= Length; cell_ptr = cell_ptr + 1) begin
        if (tp_coeff[cell_ptr+1]==1)
          Y[cell_ptr] = Y[cell_ptr-1] ^ Y[Length];
        else 
          Y[cell_ptr] <= Y[cell_ptr-1];
        Y[1] <= Y[Length];
      end
    end
endmodule

//LFSR_tb.v
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
//`include"LFSR.v"
module LFSR_tb();
  parameter Length=8;
  parameter initial_state=8'b1000_0001;
  parameter[1:Length]tp_coeff=8'b1111_0011;

  reg clk,rst;
  wire [1:Length]Y;

  AUTO_LFSR dut(
    .clk        (clk),
    .rst        (rst),
    .Y          (Y)
  );

  /* Generate periodic clock
   */
  initial clk=0;
  always #1 clk=~clk;

  /* Assert reset for several clock cycles
   */
  initial begin
    rst=1;
     #10 rst=0;
    #100 $monitor("This is the cllk %b %b %b", tp_coeff, Y, clk);
    #200 $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Sir , your code works absolutely fine , I see an additional rst=1 , in the initial block of your testbench , can you tell me what is the difference if I initialize rst=1 in a different initial block(as done in my code).
Thanks!

Comment: You have two assignments to `rst` in two different `initial` blocks, both with zero delay. There's no guarantee which assignment will "win", but it's very likely that most simulators will take the final one as it appears in the source code. Therefore, your `rst` is never asserted during a `posedge clk`, which is required to initialize `Y`. In my code, I assert `rst` in just **one** place, and leave it asserted through several clock cycles before negating it.

Answer (score 0):

> I implemented it exactly how it was mentioned in Ciletti book

No, you did not:

```
for(cell_ptr=0;cell_ptr<Length;cell_ptr=cell_ptr+1)
...
   Y[cell_ptr]=Y[cell_ptr-1]^Y[Length];
```

Gives a negative index: -1 which will produce an X.
if you check the text you will see that the for loop starts at 2.

Also, as Dave Tweed pointed out, you else is wrong:

```
....
else
  Y[cell_ptr]<=Y[cell_ptr-1];
Y[1]<=Y[Length]; // << should always execute
```

And you never assert your reset.

Just as a side note:
Although you can use an index of [1..N], it is customary to define all Verilog vectors as [N-1:0]. It make your code more compatible with 99.9% of the code out there.

Comment: That isn't the only error. Look at the `else` clause of the inner `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you I missed that one.

Comment: Still , even after making the changes I'm getting x as output.